# Laravel Eloquent conditional where depending on certain attribute

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a basic SQL request that I want to 'transform' in Eloquent query:

```
SELECT fmd.*, ff.iFormTypeCode
FROM FormMembersData fmd
INNER JOIN FormFields ff USING(iFormFieldCode)
WHERE fmd.iFormMemberCode = ".$iFormMemberCode." AND IF(ff.bLinkCurrentPeriod = 1, fmd.iPeriodCode = ".$iPeriodCode.", fmd.iPeriodCode = 0)
```

Problem is, I have no idea how to represent the condition in order to insert the right period code (0 or the variable one).

For now, this is pretty much the only query I managed to build:

```
$aMemberData = Member::find($id)
->data()
->with('field')
->where('iPeriodCode', '=', $iPeriodCode)
->get();
```

Comment: With complex query I suggest you to stick with Raw SQL. You can run DB::select("raw query"); if you need

Comment: Okay thanks, but if possible I would really appreciate to know if it possible with Eloquent :)

Comment: Beautiful avatar @lightalex

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing :

```
Member::find($id)
->data()
->join('fields', 'fields.iFormFieldCode', '=', 'membersData.iFormFieldCode')
->whereRaw(\DB::raw('IF(fields.bLinkCurrentPeriod = 1, membersData.iPeriodCode = '.$iPeriodCode.', membersData.iPeriodCode = 0)'))
->get()
->toArray();
```